# Variable length like operator

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I realize this code isn't terribly messy and so it probably isn't necessary, but is it possible to condense the lines

```
Select Case True
    Case Info.Feed Like "F#" Or Info.Feed Like "F##" Or Info.Feed like "F###"
        'stuff; Info is a class variable
    Case Else
        'there are more cases but this is all I need to keep things clear
End Select
```

into something without an `Or`?  To tell Excel that when I say #, that doesn't mean a one digit number necessarily?

Comment: `left(info.feed,1)="F"` ???

Comment: Oh god, I'm a dumbass.  How could I forget about that?  Thank you.  (I mean, I'm still curious if there is an answer to my original question, but...how did I forget that?)

Comment: there is `like "F*"` maybe with `AND len(x)<=4` perhaps

Comment: I had to discard my answer :D @Nathan_Sav. I would recommend that you put one

Comment: Could Feed contain for example.. `FX`? i.e. X is not a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/like-operator) operator and hitting its limits then you can use regular expressions in VBA quite concisely. In your case using `F*` will allow `FXXX` and `F12X` etc which I assume you don't want.

F#, F## and F### are all saying F followed by 1 to 3 digits which can be done in a single regex:

```
^F\d{1,3}$
```

Which is start of string, an `F`, 1-3 digits, end of string.

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim InfoFeed As String: InfoFeed = "F123x"

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegex.Pattern = "^F\d{1,3}$"

    If objRegex.Test(InfoFeed) Then
        Debug.Print "Do stuff"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Do other stuff"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Er, not to sound like a complete fool here, but what is a regex?  It seems really useful, and I'm always happy to learn a new tool to use, but I've never even heard of this before.

Comment: Regex is a kind of advance version of 'Like' - there's a good write up here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 3):

```
Info.Feed like "F*" And isnumeric(mid(Info.Feed,2))
```

This would catch

```
F01
F100
F99999
```

But would ignore

```
F
FX
FX01
F01A
A01
```

If you want to limit it to F000 to F999, then add a `LEN`

Answer (score 1):

`like "F*"` maybe with `AND len(x)<=4` perhaps, or simply `left(info.feed,1)="F"` if it is not length dependant.